# How to post array with array data in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have to post data like this
[image]

here data is array with array.
in interface I have written

```
@FormUrlEncoded
        @POST
        Call<ResponseModel> add_to_sheet(
                                        @HeaderMap HashMap<String, String> headers,
                                        @Url String url,
                                         @Field("data[]") ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data,
                                         @Field("insert") String insert,
                                         @Field("sheet_id") String sheet_id,
                                         @Field("sheet_name") String sheet_name
        );
```

In activity

```
private void add_to_sheet(){

        String url = "http://domainname.com/index.php";


        String m_insert = "yes";
        String m_sheet_id = mEdtSheetId.getText().toString();
        String m_sheet_name = mEdtSheetName.getText().toString();
        date = mEdtDate.getText().toString();
        category = mEdtCategory.getText().toString();
        amount = mEdtAmount.getText().toString();

        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> m_data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

        ArrayList<String> value = new ArrayList<>();
        value.add(date);
        value.add(category);
        value.add(amount);
        m_data.add(value);


        final Call<ResponseModel> call_api = RetrofitAPI.getService().add_to_sheet(getHeader(),url, m_data, m_insert, m_sheet_id, m_sheet_name);
        call_api.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseModel> call, Response<ResponseModel> response) {
                if(response.body() != null){
                    ResponseModel response_data = response.body();
                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error Occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });
    }
```

I cannot request to server. I got no error all data is in variable. I think problem is in requesting to server

Comment: You are passing `data[]` as parameter in you code and at same time passing `data` in `postman`

Comment: if I write ````data```` as parameter then also it is not working

Comment: What type of error you are getting in `onFailure`? right now you are displaying toast with hardcode text instead show actual error

Comment: I get toast from onResponse i.e Success. It will not reach to onFailure function.